# Зайти в транспорт Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

хочу сделать так : при нажатии на какую либо кнопку, персонаж перемещается в транспорт( а именно самокат), пока что самокат это обычный обьект без скрипта,и какой нужно кодл добавить к персонажу и самокату,чтобы при нажатии на какую либо кнопку персонаж садился в самокат

Comment: К персонажу и самокату нужно добавить код на C#, в котором написать логику посадки персонажа на самокат

Comment: Спасибо! А можно пример такого кода?

Comment: С таким вопросом вам надо идти на фриланс площадку и заказывать программистов, чтобы они сделали вам вашу задумку. На этой площадке никто не будет заниматься вашей задачей.

Answer (score 3):

Если в двух словах:

- нужна анимация для посадки в транспорт
- нужна логика блокировки управления если перс садится в транспорт
- Нужно сделать дочерним обьектом персонажа по отношению к транспорту
- Нужно разблокировать управление транспортом
- И, конечно же, реализовать логику управление самим транспортом

Примера такого кода тебе никто не даст ибо это очень много работы. И вне кода в том числе - та же анимация, логика переходов анимаций и т.д.

Хочешь увидеть что-то приблизительное - погугли по запросу "Enter Car Animation" и дальше играйся от того что увидишь по запросу.

По поводу качества вопроса - он более чем плохого качества. Пожалуста, почитай в справке [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)